# How to enable auto backup to ICloud in React Native?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, icloud

According to [this info page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207428), any app data from IOS apps should be synced to iCloud.

I tried adding iCloud in Xcode under "Signing & Capabilities", but sadly the app does not appear in the IOS Settings > iCloud. Also, when I reinstall the app, all data is lost.

How can I enable this for my React Native app?

Is there something similar to the `android:allowBackup=”true”` from the android part to make it work?